# Inverse character a to z

Tags: c, for-loop

In code below there is a `;` after the `for` loop, but we usually do not use `;` after the `for` loop control expression(s) because this makes the loop to end, effectively having no statements.

Why it is used here and what exactly `i--` do in this code? it happen just once.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    char a[]="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
    char temp;
    int i,j;
    for(i=0;a[i];i++);
    i--;
    puts ("the initial text is:");
    puts (a);
    for(j=0;j<i/2;j++){
        temp=a[j];
        a[j]=a[i-j];
        a[i-j]=temp;
    }
    puts ("reversed text is:");
    puts (a);
    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using the `for` loop, the number of elements in the `char` array is getting counted. Check the condition in `for`. it says `a[i]`. That means, till time `a[i]` is true, [or not `null`], the `for` loop will run and after it has finished, the total number of elements will get stored in `i`.

As in `i--`, the `for` loop will break only when the condition check is `false`, i.e, when `a[i]` contains `NULL`. This time the value of `a[i]` holds the terminating `NULL` character. Here `i` is used as the index of the array, so after `i--`, `a[i]` will point to the last valid element in the array.

Comment: The exact number of elements is actually given by the index of the first invalid element in the array. (Think C++ iterators) Your last paragraph is incorrect in that it is not finding the number of elements but rather decrementing such that the index points to the last valid character in the string

Take a string "food": 'f' (0) 'o' (1) 'o' (2) 'd' (3) '\0' (4)
We obviously have four letters in this string, thus the index of the null character is 4

Comment: @JamesReed Thanks. updated my answer with clarification.

Comment: You still have the bit saying that the number of chars is one less than i. The loop terminates on the null char so the number of chars == i (zero indexing)

Answer (score 5):

When there is a `;` after the `for`, it means the `for` does not have any code after it to execute, and it's just the `for` itself.

So what it does is, it starts from the beginning of variable `a`, goes until reaches a `NULL`, or `0`, which is interpreted as a `FALSE`, and exits the `for` loop. Now `i` is the index of the `NULL` at the end of `a`, `i--` will make it the index of the last character of the variable `a`, then it starts reversing the variable.

Answer (score 3):

A C string is a an array of `char`s. A C string is said to be "null-terminated": the end of the string is indicated by the presence of the null character `'\0'`. The loop `for(i=0;a[i];i++);` increments i until the null-terminating character is found. (When a[i] is casted to a boolean for the loop termination condition, the null character is promoted to false, since it has a value of 0). Afterward, `i--;` moves index `i` down to the last valid character in the C string.

Answer (score 2):

The `for` in

```
for(i=0;a[i];i++);
```

effectively counts the length of the string.
the `i--` then takes one off the length,
then you have a loop that swaps round the chars

Answer (score 1):

```
for(i=0;a[i];i++);
```

Checks untill the last character in `a[]`.